# I want to make call in viewdidLoad

Tags: iphone, viewdidload

I want to make call to any  number as soon as viewdidload is called ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help you: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html

Basically, they say that you can place a call using a URL object, like so:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:1-408-555-5555"]];
```

Unfortunately, that's about as much control as you get at the moment. Happy coding.